# Is it possible to fill pdf Fillable forms Using PHP script from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Can we fill PDF fill-able from using a PHP script from MySQL data?

For example, I have some PDF forms that should be filled dynamically from MySQL database. Is there a way we can fill them using a PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

There are many APIs out-there to fill PDF forms for example PDFco, PDFFiller, etc. All you need is to create request specifying name of field and it's value.
I have done similar thing in one of my project using PDFco and code snippet is like following.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.pdf.co/v1/pdf/edit/add',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "async": false,
    "encrypt": false,
    "inline": true,
    "name": "f1040-filled",
    "url": "https://bytescout-com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/files/demo-files/cloud-api/pdf-form/f1040.pdf",
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].FilingStatus[0].c1_01[1]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "True"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "John A."
        },        
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_03[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "Doe"
        },        
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].YourSocial_ReadOrderControl[0].f1_04[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "123456789"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].YourSocial_ReadOrderControl[0].f1_05[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "Joan B."
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].YourSocial_ReadOrderControl[0].f1_05[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "Joan B."
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].YourSocial_ReadOrderControl[0].f1_06[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].YourSocial_ReadOrderControl[0].f1_07[0]",
            "pages": "1",
            "text": "987654321"
        }     
    ]
}',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'x-api-key: '
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I hope this will be useful to anyone who is looking to fill PDF form using rest API.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to design the HTML template with same look as it is in your PDF.
Then by using MPDF library available for php you just need to pass HTML.
Fetch data from MySQL and assign at proper place in HTML.
The source link is as below:[Click Here For MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your form in a normal HTML page, and when submitted, it will go to a PDF generator file (which of course, you'll be creating the code). I find this one great of use: [FPDF Tutorial](http://fpdf.org/)